# Puzzle : calculate value of $\pi$ given area of circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, puzzle

I have seen in many interview experiences, interviewer asks find the value of [Pi] given area of the circle. What the interviewer is looking for and what is the answer for this?

Comment: Do we also know, for instance, the radius of the circle? Knowing the area alone isn't so helpful.

Comment: Just the area isn't enough, are you sure thry don't give you the radius too? Or maybe they give you the area and ask for the radius?

Comment: No, radius is not given..i think they want to figure out something else...

Answer (score 1):

The area of circle of radius $\;r\;$ is given by the formula $\;\pi r^2\;$ ,so if we know this value is, for example $\;S\;$, then

$$\pi r^2=S\implies \pi=\frac S{r^2}$$

and you get the value of $\;\pi\;$ (up to certain accuracy, of course).